UICollectionView: Temporarily focus on subset of items, like iMessage threads or SpringBoard folders
I'm trying to achieve a collection layout where I can focus on a subset of items, visually pulling them out like Apple does with iMessage threads or folders on the SpringBoard. It's important that I can fluidly animate between the focused and unfocused states.

I'm struggling to find the best way to make this happen. Three candidates I have in mind, but I'm not sure which to try:

Use a custom UICollectionViewLayout. I already do this to achieve something like the nested layout in the first image above. But to implement the animation and focused state, should that happen inside my existing collectionviewlayout, or should I create a second collectionviewlayout for the focused state and animate to it?

Use a second CollectionView on top of the first for the focused layer. This is my current approach, and it makes blurring the background layer easy, but it's unclear how to fluidly transition the cells from their positions in the first collectionview to the second.

Do this in SwiftUI with LazyVStack and .matchedGeometryEffect. My first prototypes of this app were all SwiftUI, but I eventually fell back to UICollectionView. Now I'm second-guessing my decision due to requirements like this.


Thanks!
